# Compare two instances of Windows based on their state (Hashing)

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hashing

I don't know how to better ask this but let me give an example. Suppose that I install a Windows 8 and do some updates, install some software, and copy some files.

Can I now get a hash code for the current state of this Windows installation so that I can compare it to other hash codes and decide if two individual installations are at the same state, state being a composition of the installed updates, installed applications, and files?

Or better, is there an easier way of comparing two instances of Windows and decide if they are in the same state?

Comment: If by hashing you mean taking e.g. a md5sum of the disk image, that is going to depend on *exactly* how the OS running in the VM lays out data on disk, and *exactly* what gets written. *In theory* that should be possible, but in practice it won't be. I would recommend removing the VM part of the equation entirely and focusing on for example how to ensure that two Windows 8 installations are at the same patch level and contain the same files. That should be doable.

Comment: @MichaelKjorling Yep, that was the point actually. I inserted VM because I thought it would be easier comparing two VM instances.

Comment: The problem with taking a md5sum or similar of the disk image is that while theoretically what gets written is deterministic, at the level of what a full-disk md5sum would be looking at there is quite a few things that aren't likely to be the same. Think volume IDs, timestamps, temporary files, differences in the exact sequence of events, ...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not exactly what you are after but the [Windows System State Analyzer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/01/12/an-introduction-to-the-windows-system-state-analyzer.aspx) lets you take a snapshot of your PC and then later on compare the current state of the PC with an earlier snapshot to help you determine what changed.